# it is a question about use vue to make a website login function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

when I write like this:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to: any, from: any, next: any) => {
  const token = userStore.token
  const username = userStore.username
  if (token) {
    if (to.path == '/login') {
      next({ path: '/home' })
    } else {
      if (username) {
        next()...
```

the login function is ok

But when I write like this(I write define token and username outside the router.beforeEach)
the page will not jump to '/home' , I need to refresh the page, then it will jump

```
const token = userStore.token
const username = userStore.username
router.beforeEach(async (to: any, from: any, next: any) => {
  if (token) {
    if (to.path == '/login') {
      next({ path: '/home' })
    } else {
      if (username) {
        next()...
```

Can you tell me why or what cause the difference
Thank you!

Comment: Try change first if to `if (userStore.token) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the difference is, when you access the username and the token outside of the router.beforeEach route it will only be initialized once when the router is loaded. So the username and token are read only once.

When you call it inside beforeEach the username and the token are freshly set every iteration of the router, so its always the latest user state.